# Sorting numbers in descending order

Tags: vb.net

I have 20 textboxes. each contains a particular number . I want the textbox1 to textboxN to have the numbers in the descending order. If any of the textbox has a zero value then I want to leave that textbox as it is. A sample code in vb.net needed.

Comment: this is unclear.  what exactly do you want in the textboxes?  can you give a better example?

Comment: I am trying to sort the numbers in descending order and then reasign the values of each textbox such that textbox1.......to....textboxN contains a values in descending order.

Comment: This is a too trivial question. Think a little and you'll find it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  Dim txt As New List(Of TextBox)
    Dim q = From i In txt 
            Where CInt(i.Attributes("value")) > 0 
            Order By CInt(i.Attributes("value")) Descending 
            Select i
```

Whana try some simple linq query over your collection?

Answer (score 6):

'for sorting the elements in descending order

```
   dim array(4) as integer 
     array(4)={4,6,2,9,1}
       'first sort the array and then reverse it as
      array.sort(4)
      array.reverse(4)
     sortlistbox.item.add(array(4))
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is a bit old, but I ran into the same problem.

Using MSDN I found this: [Enumerable.OrderBy Method (IEnumerable, Func)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you just add `.Reverse` to that query, it's descending:

```
Dim query As IEnumerable(Of Pet) = pets.OrderBy(Function(pet) pet.Age).Reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

@Thom Morgan

> This one is a bit old, but I ran into the same problem.
>   Using MSDN I found this: Enumerable.OrderBy Method (IEnumerable, Func)
>   If you just add .Reverse to that query, it's descending:

```
Dim query As IEnumerable(Of Pet) = pets.OrderBy(Function(pet) pet.Age).Reverse
```

This worked like a charm! Thank you!