# Excel pulling in the wrong data

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, connection-string

I want to get the data displayed in the cell ( for example AA2 `00:43.6`), not the value that's written above `12:00:44 AM`.
How can I manage to do so without any API etc.
Check this image from my excel 2010 example for more info:

[image: Image from excel example]

Here is my code for importing the excel file

```
MyConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & _
                          path & "';Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";") 
'i also tried IMEX=0

dtTimes = New DataTable
Dim sqlstrTimes As String = "SELECT [RACETIME] " & "FROM [SheetH$];"
'SheetF$
Try
    Dim MyCommandHistory As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstrTimes , MyConnection)
    MyCommandHistory.Fill(dtTimes )
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK
            , MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
Finally
    MyConnection.Close()
End Try
```

I checked the website of [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2010) for excel-2010, but no luck there.

Comment: Did you try declaring `sqlstrTimes` as Date? It looks like type conversion problem.

Comment: I understood that in the cell the value is displayed as `MM:SS.ms` meaning minutes:seconds.milliseconds as in `00:43.6`. The actual value of the cell is a time like `12:00:44 am`. You would like to know how to store the excel value in SQL as `MM:SS.ms` instead of a time value. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I want to retrieve the displayed value. Which is 00.43.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it this way :

1. Set connection string to read excel file without header (`HDR=NO`). Column name will be autogenerated for each column starting from `F1` to `Fn`.
2. Fill `DataTable` the way you currently do
3. Remove first row from `DataTable` since it actually column header name in excel

With that you'll get the text instead of DateTime value from excel. In my understanding, that because excel determines data type from the first row. So with this hack the first row is a text (the header) hence decided that the column is of type text/string.

```
MyConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & _
                          path & "';Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"";") 

dtTimes = New DataTable
Dim sqlstrTimes As String = "SELECT [F1] " & "FROM [SheetH$];"

Try
    Dim MyCommandHistory As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstrTimes , MyConnection)
    MyCommandHistory.Fill(dtTimes)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK
            , MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
Finally
    MyConnection.Close()
End Try

dtTimes.Rows[0].Delete()
```

Comment: Verry strange, but it did the trick!
I did run into an other problem, I wasn't able to sort by date.
But I fixed it, here is how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878324/sorting-numbers-in-descending-order/21546582#21546582