# Random Sequence Generator Visual Basic .net

Tags: vb.net, random, multiple-columns

Is there any way to create something like this in Visual Basic .Net? 
http://www.random.org/sequences/

All I want is 10 unique random numbers, 1 to 10 to be in 2 columns, 5 each, like this output: http://www.random.org/sequences/?min=1&max=10&col=2&format=html&rnd=new.

I know how to create unique random numbers, but I don't know how to sort them randomly in 2 columns each time I call the function.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: WinForms or Web page?

Comment: for the values, you probably want a Shuffle (set of values in random order) for which there are numerous answers here; for the 2 columns, that is just output but we have no idea what you are printing to

Comment: You could put them into lists, then sort the lists.

Comment: What is the point of sorting random values? Also is this a `UI` question, or an algorithm question?

Comment: I want WinForms, it may work if i shufle 10 numbers either. What i really dont know because im new its how to list them in 2 columns after the shufle or generated.I was thinking to create 2 Groupboxes with 5 labels each to print the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good solution for your problem. [random generator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/423229/CsharpRandomStringGenerator)

Take the "Unique strings test" sample. At Stackocerflow you also find good solutions for sorting your result. Fir example see this post: [sorting numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878324/sorting-numbers-in-descending-order)